# Friendly urls in my PHP application

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

I want to change my URLs in a PHP application so that it uses friendly urls.

If i start it the url = localhost/Inhaalopdracht/MEOK1/MVCthuis/boeken/index.php?author=1

I want it to be something like: localhost/Inhaalopdracht/MEOK1/MVCthuis/boeken/index.php/author/1

This is my index:

```
<?php
//lees de controller
require_once("controller/Controller.php");

//start de controller
$controller = new Controller();
$controller->start();
?>
```

My controller:

```
<?php
require_once("model/Model.php");

class Controller
{
    public $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new Model();
    }

    public function start()
    {
        if(!isset($_GET['book']) && !isset($_GET['author']))
        {
            $books = $this->model->getBookList();
            include 'view/booklist.php';
        }
        else if(isset($_GET['book']))
        {
            $book = $this->model->getBook($_GET['book']);
            include 'view/viewbook.php';
        }
        else if(isset($_GET['author']))
        {
            $author = $this->model->getAuthor($_GET['author']);
            $books = $this->model->getBookList();
            include 'view/viewauthor.php';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

And an example of one of the pages with info:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>De boekenlijst </title>
</head>

<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th> Titel </th>
        <th> Schrijver </th>
        <th> ISBN </th>
    </tr>

<?php
foreach ($books as $key => $book)
{
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td><a href="index.php?book=' . $book->id . '">' . $book->title . '</a></td>';
  echo '<td><a href="index.php?author=' . $book->id . '">' . $book->author . '</a></td>';
  echo '<td>' . $book->isbn . '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: read about url rewrite (mod_rewrite)

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC.

Comment: you can do this with htaccess

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for you. Try this one.

In this case you have to use a 301 Redirect of URLS. Here is an example:

Redirect

```
localhost/a1/articles.php?id=1&name=abc
```

to

```
localhost/article/1/abc
```

Modify the .htaccess file with the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)&name=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^articles\.php$ /article/%1/%2? [R=301]
RewriteRule ^article/([^-]+)/([^-]+)$ /articles.php?article_id=$1&article_name=$2 [L]
```

Comment: did u got the answer...?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to enable the Apache mod_rewrite extension.
And then to place a .htaccess file in the document root directory of your server, which contains something like this. It should do the job:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^Inhaalopdracht/MEOK1/MVCthuis/boeken/index.php/author/?$    Inhaalopdracht/MEOK1/MVCthuis/boeken/index.php?author=$1    [NC,L]
```

Check the tutorial for further details: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/